# Can't install new python module [Ubuntu 15.10]

Tags: python, ubuntu, module

Im so new to ubuntu and still trying to learn it.

I've installed several modules such as numpy, scipy without a problem because they can be installed via easy_install or pip commands. But I've faced a module which I don't know how to install it.

The module Im trying to install is,
https://github.com/breuleux/bugland

I've tried editing bash_profile , bashrc and profile files. like this,

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/documents/bugland-master/bugland"
```

But that doesn't seem to work neither.

Comment: For me it seems, you cannot actually install it because it's not a package. You need to clone it/fork it, and write your code in the root folder of the local repo

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on askubuntu.com

Comment: Isn't it wrong to just add it to root folder because of the update issues ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow these steps :

- `git clone https://github.com/breuleux/bugland.git`
- `sudo mv bugland/bugland /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` (or python3)

then you can import all modules in your python apps

```
from bugland import bug
```

Comment: this worked great! Still I've changed
**sudo mv bugland/bugland /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/**

to

**sudo mv bugland/bugland /home/<username here>/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/**

Thank you!