# Python : can't install new packages ubuntu 15.10

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to install plotly and I get this error `Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1`

I actually get this error each time I try to install any new package 
I have tried many suggested solutions and none works for me:

[Can't install new python module [Ubuntu 15.10]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35929914/cant-install-new-python-module-ubuntu-15-10)

I tried this: `python -m pip install plotly`

and this `sudo pip install plotly`

Output:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 839, in resolve

raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)

pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'ruamel.yaml>=0.10.7'distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

---

```
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-azNxLO/plotly
Storing debug log for failure in /home/tyahmed/.pip/pip.log
```

Comment: How are you trying to install? What's the full output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link to install plotly.- http://installion.co.uk/ubuntu/wily/universe/p/python-plotly/install/index.html

```
sudo apt-get install python-plotly
```